# Why is the angle of the wheels in this ackermann steering system so low?

Tags: mobile-robot, geometry, steering

I am trying to implement Ackermann Steering in Fusion 360. However, I am unsure why the maximum angle of my wheels is capped at such a low turning angle. Are there any issues with my design or with the links? The main joint I am moving has no effect upon increasing its angle greater than 10 degrees.

[image]